# Treatment of Underflow from Log CDF Values in Rcpp

Tags: r, c++

I'm currently writing an R package using Rcpp, and need to evaluate a log-likelihood that utilizes a beta distribution. Depending on the size of the data (affecting the a and b parameters in the beta), some of the left-tailed beta distribution probabilities end up being really small. Since I'm taking logs, I end up with an underflow issue. For example:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(inline)
src <- "double x = Rf_pbeta(0.8, (double) 6403, (double) 21, 1, 1);
        return(Rcpp::wrap(x));"
fun <- cxxfunction(signature(), src, plugin = "Rcpp")
```

If you run this code, you get warning:

> Warning message:
>   In fun() :
>     pbeta(*, log.p=TRUE) -> bpser(a=6403, b=21, x=0.8,...) underflow to -Inf

I know that I can probably use an if-statement to replace -Inf with -DBL_MAX in the function itself to fix subsequent calculation issues, but presumably this doesn't get rid of the warning message. Any idea on how to suppress the warning message (or to handle this issue more gracefully)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `suppressWarnings(cxxfunction(...))` ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should be providing exactly the same interface as R itself. And as you already use that we can just do it in R:

```
R> pbeta(seq(0.2, 0.8, by=0.1), 6403, 21, log=TRUE)
[1] -10176.71  -7583.18  -5744.24  -4319.09  -3156.15  -2174.90      -Inf
Warning message:
In pbeta(seq(0.2, 0.8, by = 0.1), 6403, 21, log = TRUE) :
  pbeta(*, log.p=TRUE) -> bpser(a=6403, b=21, x=0.8,...) underflow to -Inf
R>
```

So R should (of course) be as precise here as it can -- that is what we get from the hard work of detail-obsessed Serious Statisticians (TM) like Martin Maechler.  I think you should try this question on r-devel as I do not see anything that Rcpp does wrong here -- it just marshals the very values to the very functions R itself uses.

Lastly, you used `Rf_pbeta` which is my least favourite idiom.  Consider either the scalar `R::pbeta` or the (Rcpp sugar-based) vectorised `Rcpp::pbeta`.

Comment: Dirk, thank you for answering my question. Indeed I'm not claiming that Rcpp or R is doing anything wrong, but that I am trying to figure out how to modify my own code to handle the situation gracefully. Per Rcpp documentation, I can certainly use something along the lines of:

    if (x == R_NegInf) { }

to detect the warning. I'm wondering if there's a way to catch this specific underflow warning so that the user does not get notified (since I will be dealing with it within the if-statement). The suppressWarnings() suggestion would suppress all warnings... which is dangerous.